# Basic PHP Class Creation Cause Parse Error: Parse Error

Tags: php, ajax

```
 <?php


  class TEST{
    public $x=1;
    private $y=2;
    
    public function changeA($val){
      //$this->x = $val;
      echo "X-->".$this->x;
    }
    
    private function changeB($val){
      //$this->y = $val;
      echo "Y-->".$this->y;
    }
  }
  
  $a = new TEST();

  $a->changeA(3);
  # 
  $a->changeB(4);
```

This is really bugging me, I use all the correct syntax but I got error right on the line I do `CLASS test`.

```
Parse error: parse error in file.php on line x
```

Tested:
-Remove vars, functions, new objects. nothing fix it.

====Updated Code above, but still, the same error.

I think there is something wrong with my php... I am now running all different kind of code, even echo return the same error. I think there is some other trouble with my php setup.

===Last update

I was using Ajax to passing value and write into a php file with 755 and public access. It was seem like a kind of process hiccup. Now it functioning correctly. But the example still, really useful. **Well, don't know what is the vote down for, its seem make sense to mark reason for vote down as well like the ones who need to vote to close it.** So SO can as least know the reason for the vote down. Interesting right? Someone who actually care about improving this.

Comment: no need to put ';' after function définition
and as  Kisaragi said

Comment: Why are you trying to access a private function via an object ?

Comment: @KunalGupta It did not even get to that step yet, and that was just testing programming concept for myself.

Answer (score 2):

Class method definitions are not statements, and therefore should not be terminated with `;`.

This means that the `};` on lines 11, 16 and 17 should simply be `}` instead.

On another note, I don't know what version of PHP you're using. I'm using PHP 5.5 and got a very clear message:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';', expecting function (T_FUNCTION) in test.php on line 11

Answer (score 0):

It's always good to practice on simple examples to make its own idea about how it works.

This might help to clarify things.

```
class test
{
    public $x; 
    private $y; 

    function __construct() {
        echo "-- Constructor --<br/>";
        $this->changeX(1);
        $this->changeY(2);
        echo "-- Exiting Constructor --<br/>";
    }   

    public function changeX($val) {
        $this->x = $val;
        echo "X-->".$this->x."<br/>"; // for debugging purpose only
    }   

    private function changeY($val) {
        $this->y = $val;
        echo "Y-->".$this->y."<br/>"; // for debugging purpose only
    }   

    public function changeYprivate($val) {
        $this->changeY($val); // can call private method here
    }   

    public function getY() {
        return $this->y;
    }   
}  

  $objTest = new test();

  echo "X is ".$objTest->x." and Y is ".$objTest->getY()."<br/>";
  $objTest->changeX(3);
  $objTest->x = 10; // ok x is public, it can be modified
  $objTest->changeYprivate(4);

  // $a->changeY(4); // Error : cannot call this function outside the class !
  // $objTest->y = 20; // Error : y is private !
  // echo $objTest->y; // Error ! Can't even read y because it's private

  echo "X is ".$objTest->x." and Y is ".$objTest->getY()."<br/>";
```

Output:

```
-- Constructor --
X-->1
Y-->2
-- Exiting Constructor --
X is 1 and Y is 2
X-->3
Y-->4
X is 10 and Y is 4
```